# Service is not waking up device as it should

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-5.0-lollipop

My application do a repeating request each second - asking the server for a new data, and if there is such - it wakes up the device and run the main application.
( this is by the request from the users, and they does not care about the battery usage, it is mandatory to run each second. It is Highly Critical Operation )
( any changes to the settings which could help is allowed by the user )

I am curently trying to achieve this by using either `AlarmManager` or `System.Threading.Timer` ( tried with both ), but each time I am ending up with the follow issue :

- The device stop requesting the server at some point while it is slept and at some look-like random time it restore it's work for a short. Why this happens, and how to fix this issue ?

( OS : Android 5.x )

The code from the variation of the service in Java ( using AlarmManager )

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add( Calendar.SECOND, ConfigReader.serviceRepeatInterval );

        Intent intent = new Intent( this, SaleService.class );

        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService( this, 0, intent, 0 );

        AlarmManager alarm = ( AlarmManager )getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE );

        alarm.setRepeating( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), ConfigReader.serviceRepeatInterval, pintent );
```

The code from the variation of the service is C# ( Xamarin ) using Timer.

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {

            if( _powerManager == null )
            {
                 _powerManager = (PowerManager)this.GetSystemService(PowerService);
                _wakeLock      = _powerManager.NewWakeLock( WakeLockFlags.Full | WakeLockFlags.AcquireCausesWakeup | WakeLockFlags.OnAfterRelease, mySaleServiceWakeLock );
                 vibrator      = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService( Context.VibratorService );                
            }

            timer = new System.Threading.Timer( getCurrentPendingObjects, null, timerRepeatInterval, Timeout.Infinite );

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
```

Comment: post your code where you set the alarm please

Answer (score 1):

Using `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` or `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` will wake the device up when the alarm fires.

> The device stop requesting the server at some point while it is slept
>   and at some look-like random time it restore it's work for a short.
>   Why this happens, and how to fix this issue?

This might happen because your `PendingIntent` is calling a `Service`. This way the device can go back to sleep before `onStartCommand()` gets executed.
You should use a `BroadcastReceiver` instead (since a `WakeLock` is "guaranteed" during `onReceive()`), aquire a `WakeLock` in `onReceive()`, start your `Service` from there and release your `WakeLock` from the `Service`, when appropriate.

Although, repeating a request every second for an extended period of time (and even when the device is in sleep) seems like a terrible design. It will drain the battery pretty fast.

You should rethink your implementation, maybe use some sort of a callback mechanism instead, or at least increase the intervals between the requests (significantly).